# What's the difference between the SQS batch window duration and ReceiveMessage wait time seconds?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

You can specify SQS as an event source for Lambda functions, with the option of defining a [batch window duration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-eventsource).

You can also specify the `WaitTimeSeconds` for a `ReceiveMessage` call.

What are the key differences between these two settings?

What are the use cases?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What do you mean by 'Lambda Receive message wait time'? Can you point to what you exactly mean in the docs? Do you mean the difference between batch size and batch window as the 2 options for SQS event sources?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Hi. 
No, Receive message wait time is a setting for SQS itself, you can find it if you open edit for any SQS. For Batch size you got it right.
So form a short description they are doing basically the same.

Comment: Hi, sorry for long response. Yes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**They're fundamentally different.**

---

The receive message wait time setting is a setting that determines if your application will be doing [long or short polling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-short-and-long-polling.html). You should (almost) always opt for long polling as it helps reduce your costs; the *how* is in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-short-and-long-polling.html#sqs-long-polling).

It can be set in 2 different ways:

- on the queue level, by setting the [`ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SetQueueAttributes.html) attribute
- on the message level, by setting the [`WaitTimeSeconds`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html#API_ReceiveMessage_RequestParameters) property on your `ReceiveMessage` calls

It determines how long your application will wait for a message to become available in the queue before returning an empty result.

---

On the other hand, you can configure an SQS queue as an event source for Lambda functions by adding it as a trigger.

When creating an SQS trigger, you have 2 optional fields:

- batch size (the number of messages in each batch to send to the function)
- batch window (the maximum amount of time to gather SQS messages before invoking the function, in seconds)

The batch window function sets the `MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds` attribute for SQS event source mapping.

It's the maximum amount of time, in seconds, that the Lambda poller waits to gather the messages from the queue before invoking the function. The batch window just ensures that more messages have accumulated in the SQS queue before the Lambda function is invoked. This increases the efficiency and reduces the frequency of Lambda invocations, helping you reduce costs.

It's important to note that it's defined as the *maximum* as it's *not guaranteed*.

As per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html#stream-events), your Lambda function may be invoked as soon as any of the below are true:

- the batch size limit has been reached
- the batching window has expired
- the batch reaches the payload limit of 6 MB

---

To conclude, both features are used to control how long *something* waits but the resulting behaviour differs.

In the first case, you're controlling how long the poller (your application) could wait before it detects a message in your SQS queue & then immediately returns. You could set this value to 10 seconds but if a message is detected on the queue after 5 seconds, the call will return. You can change this value per message, or have a universal value set at the queue level. You can take advantage of long (or short) polling with or without Lambda functions, as it's available via the AWS API, console, CLI and any official SDK.

In the second case, you're controlling how long the poller (inbuilt Lambda poller) could wait before actually invoking your Lambda to process the messages. You could set this value to 10 second and even if a message is detected on the queue after 5 seconds, it may still not invoke your Lambda. Actual behaviour as to when your function is invoked, will differ based on batch size & payload limits. This value is naturally set at the Lambda level & not per message. This option is only available when using Lambda functions.

---

You can’t use both together as long/short polling is for a constantly running application or one-off calls. A Lambda function cannot poll SQS for more than 15 minutes and that is with a manual invocation.

For Lambda functions, you would use native SQS event sourcing and for any other service/application/use case, you would manually integrate SQS.

---

They're same in the sense that both aim to help you to ultimately reduce costs, but very different in terms of where you can use them.

Comment: Hi.  Nice write up.  It helped me a lot.  I have a question.  You mentioned first case and second case.  What setting is first case and what is for second case?  I am assuming BatchSize for first case and BatchWindow for second case.  Let me know if my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: Nice one. What if `batch window` is set to 0 (which is default) on a lambda resource mapping? How long will the puller wait in this case?